# Pipes into data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I trying to extract one number from ineq function (package ineq). I can extract number which I require separately in two steps:

```
#Code
library(ineq)
library(dplyr)


DATA_REFORM<-rnorm(1000, 3, .25)

gx<-data.frame(round(ineq(DATA_REFORM,type="Gini",na.rm = TRUE),4))
gx[1,1]
```

Results from this lines of codes is [1] 0.0477. But my intention is to put this lines of codes into one data frame.I try with this codes below but I make some mistake probably relate with pipes. So can anybody help me how to fix this code and get results 0.0477 but into data frame ?

```
INEQ_TOTAL_INCOME_OUTPUT<-data.frame(
  "Gini coefficient of pre-tax income"=gx<-data.frame(round(ineq(DATA_REFORM,type="Gini",na.rm = TRUE),4))%>% gx[1,1]  # Gini coefficient of pre-tax income
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
INEQ_TOTAL_INCOME_OUTPUT<-data.frame(
  "Gini coefficient of pre-tax income" = 
         round(ineq::ineq(DATA_REFORM,type="Gini",na.rm = TRUE),4), 
         check.names = FALSE
)

INEQ_TOTAL_INCOME_OUTPUT
#  Gini coefficient of pre-tax income
#1                             0.0484
```

Comment: I posted some similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660718/extract-with-number-from-ic2-function . So please if you can.Thank you in advance