# Extract with number from IC2 function

Tags: r, dplyr

I trying to extract one number from calcSConc function (package IC2). I can extract number which I require separately in two steps:

```
#CODE
library(IC2)
library(dplyr)

DATA_REFORM<-rnorm(1000, 3, .25)
DATA_REFORM1<-rnorm(5000, 6, .50)

dn_0<-calcSConc(DATA_REFORM,DATA_REFORM1)
dn_1<-data.frame(dn_0[[1]])
dn_1<-round(dn_1,6)
dn_1
```

Output from this functions is number below:

```
         index parameter
SConc 0.000115         2
```

So my intention is to put this only number 0.000115 into data frame with code below:

```
INEQ_TOTAL_INCOME_OUTPUT<-data.frame(
  "Concentration coefficient of taxes with respect to pre-tax"= round(IC2::calcSConc(DATA_REFORM,DATA_REFORM1),6)
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this code and get result 0.000115 but into data frame ?

Answer (score 1):

If we check the `str`, it is a nested `list`

```
str(dn_0)
#List of 2
# $ ineq:List of 2
#  ..$ index    : Named num -0.00054
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "SConc"
#  ..$ parameter: Named num 2
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "param"
# $ nas :List of 4
#  ..$ xNA    : num 0
#  ..$ yNA    : num 0
#  ..$ wNA    : NULL
#  ..$ totalNA: int -4000
```

So, we could directly extract those components with `[[` or `$`.  Here, we could make the `data.frame` directly on the extracted 'ineq' component

```
d1 <- transform(data.frame(IC2::calcSConc(DATA_REFORM, 
          DATA_REFORM1)$ineq), index = round(index, 6))
```

and rename the first column

```
names(d1)[1] <-  "Concentration coefficient of taxes with respect to pre-tax"
d1
#      Concentration coefficient of taxes with respect to pre-tax parameter
#SConc                                                   -0.00054         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract only the `index` part from the output :

```
data.frame("Concentration coefficient of taxes with respect to pre-tax" = 
           round(IC2::calcSConc(DATA_REFORM,DATA_REFORM1)[[1]]$index,6), 
           check.names = FALSE)

#      Concentration coefficient of taxes with respect to pre-tax
#SConc                                                  -0.000252
```